# Proof that the gaussian distribution is "symmetric".

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was trying to prove that the gaussian distribution is "symmetric",
which means that given a standard gaussian variable $N$,
$P(N\in R)=P(N\in-R)$ for all $R\subset\mathbb R$,
where $-R=\{-x:x\in R\}$.

To this end, my idea was to proceed as follows:
$$P(N\in-R)=\int_{-R}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx,$$
then use the change of variable $y=-x$,
which yields
$$P(N\in-R)=\int_{R}\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}-dy=-P(N\in R),$$
but this is a complete nonsense.

Maybe I'm doing something really dumb here but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you are considering
$-R$,
the integration is in
the reverse order,
so you get an additional sign change.

For example,
if $R = [a, b]$,
then
$P(N\in R)
=\int_a^b\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$
so
$P(N\in-R)
=\int_{-b}^{-a}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx
=\int_{b}^{a}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}d(-x)
=-\int_{b}^{a}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx
=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx
$.

I do find the notation and terminology
somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\P}[1]{\mathbb{P}\left(#1\right)}$Without loss of generality, suppose $R = [a, b]$. This implies that $-R = [-b, -a]$. (Why?) Denote $f$ to be the probability density function of the standard normal.

Then $$\P{N \in -R} = \int_{-R}f(x)\text{ d}x = \int_{-b}^{-a}f(x)\text{ d}x\text{.}$$
With the change of variable $y = -x$, $\text{d}y = -\text{d}x$, 
$$\P{N \in -R} = \int_{b}^{a}f(-y)(-\text{d}y) = \int_{a}^{b}f(-y)\text{ d}y = \int_{a}^{b}f(y)\text{ d}y = \P{N \in R}$$
since $f(y) \equiv f(-y)$.